# Performing an upsert operation from Databricks to an Azure SQL database

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm working on a way to upsert data into my Azure SQL database using PySpark. I want to use a Merge statement to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to make it work with the Azure sql database. I've tried using both spark.write and spark.read methods, but they didn't work as expected. Right now, I'm using JDBC to connect to the Azure SQL database.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *


# Connect to SQL Server using key vault credentials
scope_name = "TEST-TEST-scope"
jdbc_username = dbutils.secrets.get(scope_name, "key-username")
jdbc_password = dbutils.secrets.get(scope_name, "key-password")
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.database.windows.net:1433;database=test-database"
connection_properties = {
    "user": jdbc_username,
    "password": jdbc_password,
    "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
```

Below is my procedure definition.

```
def process_dataframe_upsert(url, dbtable, dataframe):

    dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("v_new_entries")

    upsert_sql = """
        MERGE INTO {} AS target
    USING v_new_entries AS source
    ON target.Col1 = source.Col1 and target.Col2 = source.Col2 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET target.Col3 = target.Col3 +1  
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (Col1,Col2,Date,WorkShift,ExitStatus,Col3) VALUES (source.Col1,source.Col2,source.Col3)
    """.format(dbtable)

    #return_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table="(" + upsert_sql + ") AS tmp", properties=connection_properties)
    #return return_df
    dataframe.write.jdbc(url=url, table="(" + upsert_sql + ") AS tmp", mode="append", properties=connection_properties)
```

Sample execution of the procedure is as below

```
 process_dataframe_upsert(jdbc_url, table_name, test_df)
```

The error that I get is below.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '('.

The issue seems at the call of upsert_sql in the table argument.

```
table="(" + upsert_sql + ") AS tmp"
```

Are there any alternative methods to accomplish this task more effectively?

Comment: You need to use `dataframe.write.` not `spark.write`.

Comment: oh, yes, I tried that as well, but then I got a syntax error. 
but, the syntax looks good to me, I tried executing it manually, and it worked.
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: I modified my question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limitation in Spark for using SQL queries in the Spark `table` parameter.

So, what you can do is create a staging table and run a query using [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/). Install this library using the command below.

```
pip install JayDeBeApi
```

Modify your function like this:

```py
import jaydebeapi

def process_dataframe_upsert(url, dbtable, dataframe):

    dataframe.write.jdbc(url=url, table="stg", mode="overwrite")

    upsert_sql = """
    MERGE INTO {} AS target
    USING stg AS source
    ON target.id = source.id 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET target.age =  source.age
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name_1, age) VALUES (source.id, source.name_1, source.age);
    """.format(dbtable)

    conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", url)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute(upsert_sql)
    curs.close()
    conn.close()
```

Data in the dataframe:

| id | name_1 | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | John | 25 |
| 4 | Alice | 30 |
| 5 | Bob | 35 |

Results in the table:

[image]

Here, you can see the staging table is created, and using that table, the query is executed.

You can also use `pyodbc` for this but you need to install [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu18-install,alpine17-install,debian8-install,redhat7-13-install,rhel7-offline#18) driver.

Comment: Whatever the view you are creating, it is created in databricks and not in sql database. It will fail since there will be no view named `v_new_entries` in you sql database.

Comment: good to know, and thanks for all the details, this one worked for me, I am directly writing *v_new_entries* (in overwrite mode) as a table in Azure SQL database, and then using merge,  upsert is achieved.